# Can I add friction in air?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have issue regarding speed in air.

When I jump and move simultaneously that time speed of player increase. I use impuls for jump and I use force for movement .I want to know how to slow down it when player is in air.

This is my code of movement left and right

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt :(b2Body *)ballBody :(CCSprite *)player1 :(b2World *)world
{

    if (moveRight.active==YES) 
    {   
  //      maxSpeed=10.0f;
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
    //    b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(maxSpeed,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
        ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);
    }
    else if(moveLeft.active==YES)
    {
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
        b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(-10,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
    //    ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);

    }
}
```

And following is for jumping player

```
-(void)jump:(b2Body*)ballBody:(ccTime)dt:(BOOL)touch
{
    if (touch) 
    {

        if (jumpSprte.active==YES) 
        {
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
            b2Vec2 locationWorld;
            locationWorld=b2Vec2(0,25);
            ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(locationWorld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());

        }
    }
}
```

So where i used logic??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model air resistance to slow the player down in the air. There are several ways to do this depending on how realistic you want the simulation to be. For a simple model `linearDampening` would slow it down.

True air resistance is not linear. To model this in a more realistic way you'd need to use something like this:

```
F = - C * v * |v|
```

- `F` is the total force of the air drag
- `C` is a drag constant that depends on the shape of the object
- `v` is the velocity vector ( `|v|` is the magnitude of the velocity, or length if you so wish)

It also sounds like your players are able to *increase* their speed while in the air using move. This is because you allow the player to apply force while his legs aren't touching the ground. In order to disallow this if this is your goal make sure that when the character is touching the ground is the only time when more force can be applied to make him move.

Note that this all very much depends on what sort of game you want this to be. If it looks and feels good when making physics for games it *is good*. Do not stress out if you don't manage to make a wholly accurate simulation of reality as long as the end result plays well.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question so please tell me where i used this logic??

Comment: @Leena in the update function, after you've added forces for the movement you would add a force that corresponds to the wind resistance. Also you'd want to check for contact with the ground before you check the `moveLeft` and `moveRight` things. You seem to do this in the jump function. I'd use a similar logic here, keep track of if the character touches the ground.

Comment: Yes i did it but i have only check touch only for jump because i want to move player when jump but at that time its speed gone high and its look like running on air

Comment: Reduce the amount of force when not in contact with the group. You'd get something like a super mario style game when you can move a bit in the air but not as much as when on the ground. Experiment until it looks and feels good.

Comment: As you say i am creating one bool inAir and its disable in touch detect and enable when i air.And in movement check condition if inAir enable then maxSpeed=3.0f for right and maxSpeed=-3.0f for left. IF any change require then tell me

Comment: I can't say if you're using the right logic or not. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: using linearDamping may slow down the object, but its like to slow forever but never get stop

Answer (score 0):

This is my code of movement left and right

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt :(b2Body *)ballBody :(CCSprite *)player1 :(b2World *)world
{

    if (moveRight.active==YES) 
    {   
  //      maxSpeed=10.0f;
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
    //    b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(maxSpeed,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
        ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);
    }
    else if(moveLeft.active==YES)
    {
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
        b2Vec2 locationworld=b2Vec2(-10,0);
        double mass=ballBody->GetMass();
        ballBody->ApplyForce(mass*locationworld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());
    //    ballBody->SetLinearDamping(1.2f);

    }
}
```

And following is for jumping player

```
-(void)jump:(b2Body*)ballBody:(ccTime)dt:(BOOL)touch
{
    if (touch) 
    {

        if (jumpSprte.active==YES) 
        {
            ballBody->SetActive(true);
            b2Vec2 locationWorld;
            locationWorld=b2Vec2(0,25);
            ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(locationWorld, ballBody->GetWorldCenter());

        }
    }
}
```

So where i used logic??

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting an answer if you require more help or information.